# Is the addition of "you" in Ephesians 3:13 really necessary?

Tags: greek, new-testament, ephesians

It seems to be a tradition dating back to the Vulgate to translate the Greek infinitive ἐγκακεῖν with a second-person pronoun or a second-person verb. Examples include: "[you] not to faint" (YLT), "ye faint not" (KJV) and the 2nd pl. subjunctive "ne deficiatis". (VUL) But the original Greek merely has an infinitive, no mention of a second person pronoun. Is it really necessary to interpret this infinitive in the second person, or could Paul himself possibly be the subject of the infinitive?

For example, would "wherefore, I pray not to grow weary in my tribulations for you, which is your glory" also be a plausible translation? The meaning would change, as it would be a prayer for himself, not for the Ephesians. But going by the Greek alone, it seems possible, at least to me.

What are your thoughts?

> 3:13 διὸ αἰτοῦμαι μὴ ἐγκακεῖν ἐν ταῖς θλίψεσίν μου ὑπὲρ ὑμῶν, ἥτις ἐστὶν
>   δόξα ὑμῶν.
>
> wherefore, I ask [you] not to faint in my tribulations for you,
>   which is your glory. (YLT)
>
> So I ask you not to lose heart over what I am suffering for you, which is your glory. (ESV)
>
> Wherefore I desire that ye faint not at my tribulations for you, which is your glory. (KJV)
>
> Wherefore I pray you not to faint at my tribulations for you, which is your glory. (Douay-Rheims)
>
> propter quod peto ne deficiatis in tribulationibus meis pro vobis quae est gloria vestra (VUL)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this interpretation fits the verses that follow:

> Τούτου χάριν κάμπτω τὰ γόνατά μου πρὸς τὸν πατέρα τοῦ Κυρίου ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ ... ἵνα δῴη ὑμῖν ... δυνάμει κραταιωθῆναι διὰ τοῦ Πνεύματος αὐτοῦ
>
> *For this cause I bow my knees unto the Father of our Lord Jesus Christ,
> ... that he would grant you ... to be strengthened with might by his Spirit*

Theophylact comments:

> It is necessary that I be shackled and suffer cruelly at the hands of those who do not understand the mystery, but rather dispute and oppose it.  Therefore, I beg you, my brothers, *that ye faint not*, which means, that you not be shaken and fearful, as if something irrational had occurred.  Rather, these bonds and afflictions which I endure for your sake redound to your glory.